# How to get node type in graph scala

Tags: scala, graph-theory

I am generating a graph using graph-scala library and I need to set the coordinates after building the graph.

My object are Ball and Figure extending from GraphNode. And I generate my Graph using the GraphNode object:

```
  val ball1=new Ball(1,"BALL-A")
  val figure1=new Figure(1)
  val figure2=new Figure(2)
  val figure3=new Figure(3)

  val edges = Seq(
    (ball1, figure1),
    (figure2, ball1),
    (ball1, figure3)
  )

  val graph1: Graph[GraphNode, HyperEdge] = edges
    .map({ case (node1, node2) =>
      Graph[GraphNode, HyperEdge](node1 ~> node2)
    })
    .reduce(_ ++ _)
```

And now I want to set X, Y and Width properties for each node:

```
  graph1.nodes
    .map(node => {
      node match {
        case b: Ball =>
          println("is a ball!")
          if (b.nodeType.equals("BALL-A"))
            b.copy(x = 0, y = 0, width = 100)
          else
            b.copy(x = 30, y = 30, width = 200)
        case otherType =>
          val name = otherType.getClass.getSimpleName
          println(name)
      }
      node.toJson
    })
    .foreach(println)
```

But I get the type "NodeBase" instead of setting the node. Any suggestions to set properties once I built the graph? My base issue is to get the type for each node to set the property but I am not able to.

Answer (score 0):

node has a method to get the instance class:

```
node.value match {
 ...
```

Now you can use pattern matching